# Recommend books for learning lattice QCD

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, quantum-chromodynamics, lattice-model, lattice-gauge-theory

I want to learn lattice QCD by myself, but I don't know how to start. Can you recommend some books for lattice QCD?

Comment: It would help if you explained whether you already understand QFT, continuum QCD, and lattice calculations for other theories.

Comment: I have learned QED, perturbative QCD, and gauge field theory

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, one of the best modern references is a book by **Gattringer and Lang** https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642018497. This book contains rather a broad introduction of the subject, from the elementary details, such as path integral on  lattice and different discretizations. And then there is discussion on more modern aspects, such as a various way of treating dynamical fermions on lattice, the sign problem, hadron spectroscopy, etc..

Moreover, the good reference is Thomas Degrand, Carleton DeTar - **Lattice Methods for Quantum Chromodynamics** http://en.bookfi.net/book/747102. Their content significantly overlaps, however some of the topics, not covered in the first book mentioned, can be looked up in Degrand, DeTar.

The book by **Istvan Montvay, Gernot Münster** https://books.google.ru/books?id=NHZshmEBXhcC&redir_esc=y contains more theoretical details and is more advanced, but I recommend to read it in case there is wish to get more rigorous proof or motivation for some statements, for example, justification of staggered fermions.

Comment: Very thanks. I will start to read these books you recommand.